# Loading Image Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

I have to display lots of `Image` of different size in a single page.

```
<div id="box1">
 <span>Something About Image Goes Here</span>
 <img src="img1.jpg" id="img1" />
</div>
<div id="box2">
 <span>Something About Image Goes Here</span>
 <img src="img2.jpg" id="img2" />
</div>
---
---
<div id="box30">
 <span>Something About Image Goes Here</span>
 <img src="img30.jpg" id="img30" />
</div>
```

my page will take much time to load completely if i use such code, so i want that all images should not load at once only `Images within viewport` (visible part of web page) should be loaded first and rest should load when user scrolls to them.

**Note**
I dont want it for `text` (image info i used in code), text should appear normally at once. 

As in facebook when user scroll down it loads new content but here i want only for images, i am using a decorated `div` and when user scroll down corresponding image must appear in that div. (i wants to add a loading image also till the pic loads completely)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [jQuery lazyload plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for that.

> Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading 
>   of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport (visible part 
>   of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them.

Comment: yes dear, you understand my problem well, i m reading `lazyload` that u tagged

Comment: If you are referencing lazyload plugin, I'd suggest you have a look at this plugin, based on lazyload but with support for retina-ready images. [**Unveil.js**](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil)